# Slack user id is not recognized with error: 'user_not_found'

Tags: slack-api

I am doing a fetch to the slack.com/api/users.info method using:
`return await fetch('https://slack.com/api/users.info?token=' + process.env.SLACK_AUTH_TOKEN + '&user=' + slackUserId + '&pretty=1', { method: 'POST' })`

The slack user id is correct and shows the same as I can see when clicking my profile in the Slack app, yet the Slack API can not find my user, as I get error: { ok: false, error: 'user_not_found' }.

This is the first time I have this problem, it worked before, but I did not do any changes in the code.

```
{ token: 'xxx',
  team_id: 'xxx',
  api_app_id: 'xxx',
  event:
   { client_msg_id: 'xxx',
     type: 'message',
     text: 'test',
     user: 'UE8DHTXXX', // User id here
     ts: 'xxx',
     channel: 'DK037CXXX',
     event_ts: 'xxx',
     channel_type: 'im' },
  type: 'event_callback',
  event_id: 'xxxxxxxxx',
  event_time: 1559808987,
  authed_users: [ 'xxxxxxx' ] }

Error:  { ok: false, error: 'user_not_found' }
```

[image: Slack Id]

Comment: It could be a bug, but in most cases its a bug in the code. Could you please attach the relevant part of your code to the question? Should be at least the full method, not just one line.

Comment: It was a bug. I identified users using the wrong xoxb file.